# Angular2 - return observable of object created in map function

Tags: http, angular, observable

Say I have this function...

```
public getStuff(): Observable<Stuff> {
     return.http.get('url')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .map((data: Piece) => {
               var stuff = new Stuff();
               // Apply logic to "data", modify stuff model, return stuff to subscriber
          });
}
```

How do I return the stuff object to the observer instead of the "data" of type Piece?

Comment: Doesn't `return stuff;` inside that second map function do what you ask? If not, how is it different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a code block you need an explicit `return`:

```
public getStuff(): Observable<Stuff> {
     return.http.get('url')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .map((data: Piece) => {
               var stuff = new Stuff();
               return stuff;
          });
}
```